# How to remotely access Raspberry Pi (using as SVN server)

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi

I just installed SVN on my Raspberry Pi. Everything works locally, I can commit/check-out code, view the repository in my browser, etc.

Now I just want to be able to access the repository remotely (i.e. from any computer with Internet access). What are the steps I need to take in order to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a remote repository, you have to have Subversion-server on repository-host.

- Read ["Server Configuration"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.html) chapter from SVN Book (pay attention to ["svnserve, a Custom Server"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) part, because a lightweight svnserve *may be* best choice for your Raspberry Pi).
- Configure and run svnserve and use `svn://`-accessible repositories from any another location.